# Add "scp" to "share via" or "send via" menu

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, share-menu

In the photo gallery application a pop-up menu allows selecting various destinations for "*share via*".

Is it possible to add "*scp*" to this list? There seem to be a number of scp clients out there but I don't know if any one of them can add itself to the "*share via*" menu.

Comment: What are you really asking for? Is this geared towards development?

Comment: I'd like to be able to quickly scp photos to a remote host.

Comment: That is largely dependent on if the scp client apps have that feature to enable sharing as in *share via*! Why not use Google Drive or DropBox, or even Box.net?

Comment: The thing is I haven't even found an open source / free scp client yet, do you know any?

Comment: @t0mm13b privacy? There might be certain things the user doesn't want to be in the cloud. One of the reasons I don't use such things at all ;)

Comment: Did you find a scp solution? I am interested in an updated answer, if you found something.

Answer (score 2):

Shareing is a feature the application needs to explicitly code for and then advertise to the system that it accepts share requests.  If you have an SCP app that you like but it is not offering the share feature try checking if the developer has a website with more information.  If you still have no luck try emailing the developer and asking for the feature.